# Compile HTML in Angular 6/7

Tags: angular

I am wondering if this is possible:

- I have a html page which is using some of my component.
- I want to load this html page dynamicly, it is served from the assets folder.
- I wish the componentes I use got compiled.

Currently I am doing something like this:

```
const html = this.http.get('/assets/content/chapter1.html', { responseType: 'text' });
    html.subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.content = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(res);
      },
      (err) => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('Complete')
    );
```

my template

```
<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```

is this possible?
If yes, how?

Comment: So, basically, you want to generate a component dynamically, not just the HTML?

Comment: @Joel yes, not only one component, multiple.

Comment: Okay, for this you will need a component that will generate a dynamic page. You want full access to the controllers functions also?

Comment: @Joel what do to mean with controllers functions? I want to render the page with some custom components like slider.

Comment: Lets try to clear this up... you are just trying to compile html-code? Is that all you want to do? You dont want to compile the component (as you wrote in your question)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's going to be really hard to post a working example of this because the working example that I have is generating components through JSON-files.

`dynamic-page.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, Inject, AfterViewInit, NgModule, Compiler, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentRef, OnDestroy, ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";
import { AppService } from "../../shared/app.service";
import { DynamicPageService } from "./dynamic-page.service";
import { NetgaugeKpiModule } from "../../ui-components/netgauge-kpi/netgauge-kpi.module";
import { UiGridModule } from "../ui-grid/ui-grid.module";
import { LteBoxModule } from "../../ui-components/lte-box/lte-box.module";
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { IEyesightConfig } from "../../../eyesight.config";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { CpkMonitorModule } from "../cpk-monitor/cpk-monitor.module";
import { SmallKpiBoxModule } from "../../ui-components/small-kpi-box/small-kpi-box.module";
import { IframeWrapperModule } from "../iframe-wrapper/iframe-wrapper.module";
import { LineChartModule } from "../../ui-components/charts/line-chart/line-chart.module";
import { PieChartModule } from "../../ui-components/charts/pie-chart/pie-chart.module";
import { ProgressMultiModule } from "../../ui-components/progress-multi/progress-multi.module";
import { GraphPageModule } from "../../ui-components/charts/graph-page.module";
import { DropDownsModule } from "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns";
import { APP_CONFIG } from "../../shared/constants";

@Component({
    selector: "dynamic-page",
    template: "<ng-container #vc></ng-container>",
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class DynamicPageComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
    @ViewChild("vc", { read: ViewContainerRef }) public vc: ViewContainerRef;
    private cmpRef: ComponentRef<any>;
    private data: any[] = [];
    private pageConfig: any;
    private pageConfigName: string;
    private currentId: number = 1;

    private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

    constructor(
        @Inject(AppService) private readonly appService: AppService,
        @Inject(DynamicPageService) private readonly dynamicPageService: DynamicPageService,
        @Inject(Compiler) private readonly _compiler: Compiler,
        @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private readonly appConfig: IEyesightConfig,
        @Inject(ActivatedRoute) private readonly route: ActivatedRoute,
        @Inject(Router) private readonly router: Router
    ) { }

    public getAttributeValue(configKey, value, datasources: object[], id) {
        let configValue = value;
        let attributeValue: any | any[];
        const isString = _.isString(configValue);
        const angularData = isString ? _.startsWith(configValue, "{{") : false;
        if (angularData) {
            configValue = configValue.replace("{{", "");
            configValue = configValue.replace("}}", "");
        }
        const splittedValue: string[] = isString ? configValue.split(".") : [];
        const datasourceIndex = isString ? _.findIndex(datasources, (x) => x.name.match("^" + splittedValue[0])) : -1;
        const bodyData = configKey.toLowerCase() === "body";
        if (datasourceIndex !== -1) {
            const dataPath = splittedValue.slice(1).join(".");
            const data = _.get(datasources[datasourceIndex], dataPath);
            if (angularData) {
                this.data[id + configKey] = data;
                attributeValue = `{{data['${id + configKey}']}}`;

            } else if (dataPath.length === 0) {
                this.data[id + configKey] = datasources[datasourceIndex];
                attributeValue = `data['${id + configKey}']`;
            } else if (!bodyData) {
                this.data[id + configKey] = data;
                attributeValue = `data['${id + configKey}']`;
            } else {
                attributeValue = data;
            }
        } else if (!isString && splittedValue.length === 0) {
            if (_.isArray(configValue)) {
                configValue.forEach((innerConfig, innerConfigIndex) => {
                    if (!_.isString(innerConfig)) {
                        _.keys(innerConfig).forEach((innerConfigProperty) => {
                            const innerConfigKey = configKey + innerConfigIndex + innerConfigProperty + innerConfig[innerConfigProperty];
                            innerConfig[innerConfigProperty] = this.getAttributeValue(innerConfigKey, innerConfig[innerConfigProperty], datasources, id);
                            if (_.startsWith(innerConfig[innerConfigProperty], "data[")) {
                                const dataKey = innerConfig[innerConfigProperty].match(/[^']*(?='\])/)[0];
                                innerConfig[innerConfigProperty] = this.data[dataKey];
                                // console.log(
                                //     "Property: ",innerConfigProperty,
                                //     "\nInner config key: " + innerConfigKey,
                                //     "\nData key: " + dataKey,
                                //     "\n", this.data[dataKey],
                                //     "\n\n",
                                //     "\n\n");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                _.keys(configValue).forEach((innerConfig, innerConfigIndex) => {
                    const innerConfigKey = configKey + innerConfigIndex + innerConfig + configValue[innerConfig];
                    configValue[innerConfig] = this.getAttributeValue(innerConfigKey, configValue[innerConfig], datasources, id);
                    if (_.startsWith(configValue[innerConfig], "data[")) {
                        const dataKey = configValue[innerConfig].match(/[^']*(?='\])/)[0];
                        configValue[innerConfig] = this.data[dataKey];
                    }
                });
            }
            this.data[id + configKey] = configValue;
            attributeValue = `data['${id + configKey}']`;
        } else {
            attributeValue = configValue;
        }
        return attributeValue;
    }

    public generateWidgetHtml(widget): string {
        const id = this.currentId++;
        const cssClass = widget.cssClass ? `class="${widget.cssClass}"` : "";
        let attributes = "";
        let body = "";
        const datasources = widget.dataSources ? widget.dataSources : [];
        if (widget.config) {
            _.keys(widget.config).forEach((configKey: string) => {
                let camelCaseKey: string = "";
                configKey.split("-").forEach((part, index) => {
                    if (index === 0) {
                        camelCaseKey = part;
                    } else {
                        camelCaseKey += part.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + part.substr(1);
                    }
                });
                const bodyData = camelCaseKey.toLowerCase() === "body";
                const attributeValue = this.getAttributeValue(camelCaseKey, widget.config[configKey], datasources, id);
                if (!bodyData) {
                    attributes += `${camelCaseKey}="${attributeValue}"`;
                } else {
                    body += attributeValue;
                }
            });
        }
        if (widget.widgets) {
            widget.widgets.forEach((childWidget, childIndex) => {
                body += this.generateWidgetHtml(childWidget);
            });
        }
        const widgetHtml = `<${widget.type} ${cssClass} ${attributes}> ${body} </${widget.type}>`;

        return `${widgetHtml}`;
    }

    public buildHtmlFromPageConfig(): string {
        let html = "";
        this.pageConfig.widgets.forEach((widget, index) => {
            const widgetHtml = this.generateWidgetHtml(widget);
            html += `${widgetHtml}`;
        });
        return html;
    }

    public ngAfterViewInit() {
        const sub = this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
            if (params.pagename && params.pagename.length > 0) {
                this.pageConfigName = params.pagename + ".page-config.json";
                this.appService.getPageConfig(this.pageConfigName).then((pageConfig) => {
                    this.dynamicPageService.getPageConfigWidgetsData(pageConfig).then((pageConfigWithData) => {
                        this.vc.clear();
                        this.cmpRef = null;

                        this.pageConfig = pageConfigWithData;
                        const htmlTemplate = this.buildHtmlFromPageConfig();

                        // tslint:disable-next-line:max-classes-per-file
                        @Component({
                            template: htmlTemplate
                        }) class DynamicComponent {
                            public data: any[];
                        }
                        // tslint:disable-next-line:max-classes-per-file
                        @NgModule({
                            imports: [
                                 //IMPORT ALL MODULES THAT WILL / SHOULD BE DYNAMICALLY CREATED
                            ],
                            declarations: [DynamicComponent] //this will be what is generating the code
                        }) class DynamicModule { }

                        const mod = this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(DynamicModule);
                        const factory = mod.componentFactories.find((comp) =>
                            comp.componentType === DynamicComponent
                        );
                        this.cmpRef = this.vc.createComponent(factory);
                        this.cmpRef.instance.data = this.data;
                        this.appService.hidePageLoader();
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
                        console.log("Error loading page config data: \"" + this.pageConfigName + "\": ", err);
                        this.appService.setLoadingError({ errorMessage: "Error loading page config data: \"" + this.pageConfigName + "\"", error: err });
                    });
                }).catch((err) => {
                    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
                    console.log("Error loading page config: \"" + this.pageConfigName + "\": ", err);
                    // this.appService.setLoadingError({errorMessage: "Error loading page config: \"" + this.pageConfigName + "\"", error: err});
                    this.router.navigate([this.appConfig.defaultRoute]);
                });
            } else {
                this.router.navigate([this.appConfig.defaultRoute]);
            }
        });
        this.subscriptions.push(sub);
    }

    public ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscriptions.forEach((sub) => {
            sub.unsubscribe();
        });
    }
}
```

`app-routing.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
RouterModule.forRoot(
            [
                {path: ":pagename", component: DynamicPageComponent, canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard]},
                {path: ":pagename/:pageparam", component: DynamicPageComponent, canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard]},
                {path: "**", component: DynamicPageComponent, canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard]}
            ],
            {
                useHash: true
            }
        )
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Now, create a JSON file called `YOUR-COMPONENT-NAME.page-config.json`

Now, when you attempt to navigate to `http://localhost:1337/YOUR-COMPONENT-NAME`. The dynamic-page will be called and it will look for a json-file with that name.

An example of what that file could look like is this.
In this example, we're generating 3 components, we enter some data into its `@Input` parameters and we also create a generic html-div-tag and append css-classes to it.

```
{
  "widgets": [
     {
          "type": "div",
          "cssClass": "col-md-2",
          "widgets": [
            {
              "type": "YourComponentSelector",
              "config": {
                "[inputParameterNameInYourComponent]": 0,
                "characteristic-name": "w/e",
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "div",
          "cssClass": "col-md-3" //just generate a generic div with a CSS-class.
        },
        {
          "type": "div",
          "cssClass": "col-md-2",
          "widgets": [
            {
              "type": "YourComponentSelector",
              "config": {
                "[inputParameterNameInYourComponent]": 0,
                "characteristic-name": "w/e",
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "div",
          "cssClass": "col-md-2",
          "widgets": [
            {
              "type": "YourComponentSelector",
              "config": {
                "[inputParameterNameInYourComponent]": 0,
                "characteristic-name": "w/e",
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In this file - you can structure whatever you want to be dynamically created.

Lets say you have a component called "administration.component.ts".

When you now are navigating to `/administration` dynamic-page will look for `administration.page-config.json` and build that page complete with components and html-elements.

Hope this at least helps you along the way, there are many approaches to dynamically create components, this might be a slightly more advanced approach, but it is really useful when its implemented correctly.

Comment: where did you copy-pasted this from?

Comment: My project, do u want a printscreen ?

Comment: what makes you think that I want a ss of it? lol. Just wondering, because there is **a lot** of stuff that OP doesnt need in your answer.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Yes, which i preficed in the answer. (read first sentence). well, you phrased your question like "this is plagiarism". (which it isnt)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ComponentFactoryResolver, NgModule, Compiler, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ContentDirective } from './../../directives/content.directive';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ComponentsModule } from '@components/components.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chapter',
  templateUrl: './chapter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chapter.component.scss']
})
export class ChapterComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;
  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private http: HttpClient,
    private compiler: Compiler) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadComponent();
  }

  private addComponent(template: string, properties: any = {}) {
    @Component({ template })
    class TemplateComponent { }

    @NgModule({ declarations: [TemplateComponent], imports: [ComponentsModule] })
    class TemplateModule { }


    const mod = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(TemplateModule);
    const factory = mod.componentFactories.find((comp) =>
      comp.componentType === TemplateComponent
    );
    const component = this.container.createComponent(factory);
    Object.assign(component.instance, properties);
  }

  loadComponent() {
    // let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(adItem.component);
    const html = this.http.get('/assets/content/chapter1.html', { responseType: 'text' });
    html.subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.addComponent(res);
      },
      (err) => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('Complete')
    );
  }
}
```